# php convert image url to base64

Tags: php, laravel

Is there anyway to convert image url to base64.
my current code looks like this.

```
$path = 'https://projectstaging.s3.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/2ade1776f74aa967de6578bbbceca692c274aced.png';
$type = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$data = file_get_contents($path);
$base64 = 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($data);
```

I don't want to use file_get_contents as it blocks when there is too many request and this fails.
Any better alternative.
Thanks

Comment: i tired this form given url. but its not showing base64
`<?php
$img = imagecreatefrompng('https://projectstaging.s3.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/80f1d508b80a16f7b114009c62a2794ff45a84b6.png');
ob_start();
imagepng($img);
$bin = ob_get_clean();
$b64 = base64_encode($bin);
echo $b64;
?> `

Comment: when i try to access the image url I am getting ```NoSuchBucket``` error from aws s3 bucket

Comment: here is the link of image  snapformsstaging.s3.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/80f1d508b80a16f7b114009c62a2794ff45a84b6.png

Answer (score 2):

Can you try this

```
function convertImagetoBase64($url)
{
  $urlParts = pathinfo($url);
    $extension = $urlParts['extension'];
  
  $base64 = 'data:image/' . $extension . ';base64,' . base64_encode(\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http::get($url)->body());
    return $base64;
}

$url = 'snapformsstaging.s3.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/80f1d508b80a16f7b114009c62a2794ff45a84b6.png';

$base64Txt = (convertImagetoBase64($url));
```

Live Demo [here](https://phpsandbox.io/n/green-fog-vzxv-5esyk?files=%2Fresources%2Fviews%2Fwelcome.blade.php)

Comment: I want to get base64 data from above url not image

Comment: please change change the ```$url``` varibale value to whatever you want

Comment: i did echo $base64Txt; it is not showing me base64 code

Comment: Can you check the demo now

Comment: the previous url that you provided does not exist